# Docker image failing in Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, bioinformatics, nextflow

I am trying to compress and decompress data within a nextflow pipeline using a tool called naf, https://github.com/KirillKryukov/naf,and I'm using the latest docker image 'quay.io/biocontainers/naf:1.3.0--hec16e2b_3'. I am running the pipeline in a Kubernetes cluster and I keep getting the error: Illegal instruction (core dumped), and terminated with an error exit status (132).

The tool works properly locally. I have also build my own image which also works locally, but doesn't work in the kubernetes cluster, throwing the same error. Could anyone assist?

This is section of my main.nf file to pull the container:

```
process {
   executor = 'k8s'
   scratch = true
   withName:COMPRESS{
      container = 'quay.io/biocontainers/naf:1.3.0--hec16e2b_3'
      pod {
        nodeSelector = 'templabel=pauline'
        }
   }    
   withName:DECOMPRESS{
      container = 'quay.io/biocontainers/naf:1.3.0--hec16e2b_3'
      pod {
        nodeSelector = 'templabel=node1'
        }
   }
   withName:CHECK_STRANDNESS {
      container = 'ninedem/check_strandedness:latest'
      pod {
        nodeSelector = 'templabel=node1'
        }
   }
```

and the commands to compress and decompress are these:

```
##compress
mkdir mytemp
    ennaf -o ${name}_1.trimmed.naf --temp-dir mytemp ${trimmed_reads[0]}
```

```
##decompress
unnaf --fastq ${compressed_trimmed_reads[0]} > ${name}_1.trimmed.fastq
```

Comment: Since you are asking a question about Kubernetes specifically, it might make sense for you to include the actual Kubernetes code you are using to deploy this... Show us the yaml specs for the Pod/Job/Deployment/whatever that is supposed to run this!